# name of a certain Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

What are some names for the Markov Chain
$$
X_{n+1} = X_n?
$$
I have heard this called a "[maximally uninteresting](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/f05/8931/n1998.pdf)" Markov Chain. Are there any other names? Something cooler-sounding than "constant" Markov Chain.

Comment: There's a natural category of Markov chains in which this would be a terminal universal object.

Comment: @whuber terminal? What category?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory.  A morphism between chains would merge groups of states into single states, subject to consistency criteria among the transitions with nonzero probability, essentially producing a simpler version of the original chain.